# Configure Mercurial for extdiff Directory Compare with vim on Windows

Tags: vim, mercurial

I'm running Mercurial from the command line on Windows XP. I've got the extdiff plugin. I wanted

```
hg vimdiff
```

to use Vim's DirDiff command. I've tried putting

```
cmd.vimdiff = gvim
opts.vimdiff = -f '+next' '+execute "DirDiff" argv(0) argv(1)'
```

In my Mercurial.ini. If I do hg vimdiff then gvim opens with a file name '+next'. I think the problem is to do with quoting and pathnames specific to windows. I've tried a number of permutations of backslashes and single and double quotes (not entirely randomly) but with no luck.

I've solved my problem for now by making a separate script to invoke gvim i.e.

```
[extdiff]
cmd.vimdiff = c:\python25\python.exe
opts.vimdiff = c:\test\gvimdiff.py
```

and gvimdiff.py being

```
import sys
import os

os.system('gvim -c "DirDiff %s %s"' % (sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]))
```

But if anyone knows the secret incantation to make it work direct from the command line let me know and I'll maybe try and get the documentation updated.

Comment: The accepted answer links to a blogger account that is private and the answer is no longer visible. Would you mind posting the solution?

Comment: @KenSmith I added an answer below: https://superuser.com/a/1638130/95874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a sort of bug of vim when calling a function with f-args and the args are strings ending with '\'. The solution is to remove the trailing '\' for each arg.

I have a more compact solution here:

[Using vimdiff with mercurial](http://deepnite.blogspot.com/2009/10/use-vimdiff-as-mercurial-diff-utility.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, set `opts.vimdiff` in your .hgrc file like this:

```
opts.vimdiff=-f "+next" "+execute 'DirDiff' fnameescape(substitute(argv(0), '\\$', '', '')) fnameescape(substitute(argv(1), '\\$', '', ''))"
```

If you still run into an issue after the above fix and get an error message "There is no diff at the current line!", you are most likely using a newer version of DirDiff which forces UNIX-style locale specification at the command line without checking if it's running on Windows. The fix is to add the following line to your _vimrc or .vimrc file:

```
let g:DirDiffForceLang=""
```

Details here: https://vijay.tech/talks/mercurial-diffs-with-vim-on-windows/